# python requests can not send https request

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I installed [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

But I can not send https request, even as simple as this:

```
requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```

The error message is:

```
_ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

UPDATES: I can send https request using other method, urllib2, httplib can send https request sucessfully

Comment: Works here. Where did you install requests from?

Comment: Are you using a proxy server that cannot handle https?

Comment: can you ping to that address ?

Comment: @Tichodroma I install requests using pip, in virtualenv

Comment: @MartinLuo: actually, I am more and more convinced you are, but perhaps are not aware of it. Try this on a different machine *outside* of your current network.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a problem with `requests`, or even with Python.

You are most likely using a proxy server that has not been properly configured to handle SSL connections. The exact problem is very much dependent on the proxy server. A Google search on the `140770FC` error will give you many hits and discussions on how to diagnose this.

Note that even if you have not configured a proxy on your local machine, a corporate firewall could still be forcing HTTPS connections to go over a proxy at the network boundaries.

Comment: But why urllib2, httplib can success? Also, in the same machine, I can use java to send https connection

Comment: @MartinLuo: Headers in the request causing the proxy and/or Google to behave differently perhaps? Some proxies cannot handle an SSL redirect from the server, for example.

Comment: I just use this simple code urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com'), I don't think this could have a diferent result

Comment: @MartinLuo: of course it could; requests sets a different user-agent header for example.